# SQL is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have the following error for this SQL Query

> Column 'StudentSIP.StartDate' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

```
select concat(sc.StartDate, sc.EndDate) SIPDate,
       count (sj.LOComment) WeekReviewed,
       count(sjd.WeekNo) TotalWeek,
       sum(sjj.TotalDaysRecord) TotalDaysRecord,
       count(case sjd.JournalStatusCode when 'D' then 1 else null end) PendingComplete
from StudentJournalDate sjd
left join StudentJournal sj
    on sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
left outer join
(
    select sj.WeekNo, 
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day1Journal) = '' or sj.Day1Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day2Journal) = '' or sj.Day2Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day3Journal) = '' or sj.Day3Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day4Journal) = '' or sj.Day4Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day5Journal) = '' or sj.Day5Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day6Journal) = '' or sj.Day6Journal is null then 0 else 1 end +
           case when RTRIM(sj.Day7Journal) = '' or sj.Day7Journal is null then 0 else 1 end as TotalDaysRecord 
    from StudentJournal sj
) as sjj
    on sjj.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
left outer join StudentSIP sc
    on sc.AdminNo = sjd.AdminNo
```

Comment: Is this the actual query which generated the error?  The error message seems to be saying that a grouping was done somewhere, but I don't see it.  As it is, I actually don't see any glaring problems with the query you posted above.

Comment: Yes, this is the actual query.

Comment: As you had Use aggregate function Use Group By for sc.StartDate, sc.EndDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never told us which version of SQL you are using, but I suspect is that the presence of the aggregate functions in your `SELECT` (e.g. `COUNT` and `SUM`) are putting the database into a grouping mode.  In this mode, you can only use aggregate functions of columns in the `SELECT`, or columns which appear in a `GROUP BY` clause.  Since `sc.StartDate` is neither an aggregate and you do not have a `GROUP BY` clause, you are getting this error.

One quick fix to make this error go away would be to `GROUP BY` the concatenated start and end dates, i.e. add `GROUP BY CONCAT(sc.StartDate, sc.ENDDate)` to the end of your current query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(sc.StartDate, sc.ENDDate) SIPDate,
       COUNT (sj.LOComment) WeekReviewed,
       COUNT(sjd.WeekNo) TotalWeek,
       SUM(sjj.TotalDaysRecord) TotalDaysRecord,
       COUNT(CASE sjd.JournalStatusCode WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) PENDingComplete
FROM StudentJournalDate sjd
LEFT JOIN StudentJournal sj
    ON sjd.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT sj.WeekNo, 
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day1Journal) = '' OR sj.Day1Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day2Journal) = '' OR sj.Day2Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day3Journal) = '' OR sj.Day3Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day4Journal) = '' OR sj.Day4Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day5Journal) = '' OR sj.Day5Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day6Journal) = '' OR sj.Day6Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
           CASE WHEN RTRIM(sj.Day7Journal) = '' OR sj.Day7Journal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TotalDaysRecord 
    FROM StudentJournal sj
) AS sjj
    ON sjj.WeekNo = sj.WeekNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentSIP sc
    ON sc.AdminNo = sjd.AdminNo
GROUP BY CONCAT(sc.StartDate, sc.ENDDate)  -- make error go away so you are happy again :-)
```

Comment: Hi, im trying to convert the date using this function CONVERT(varchar, sc.StartDate,103) + '" + " " + "' +  '" + " - " + "' +  CONVERT(varchar, sc.EndDate,103) SIPDate so it will display in dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy. How do i add it into the query? Thanks

Comment: You can either change the select and group by to this, or you can subquery it out.

Answer (score -1):

the sql do not work when using A**ggregate Functions** without group by clause;

ex `select key1,key2,count(*),sum(*) from tableA group by key1,key2`